# Active vs crystallized state in shasper

Tags: casper, sharding

https://notes.ethereum.org/SCIg8AH5SA-O4C1G1LYZHQ?view#

Active state means every single block produced on PoS main chain.

Crystallized state occurs every 100th block.

Only Crystallized state consists of information about validators:

```
# List of active validators
active_validators': [ValidatorRecord],
# List of joined but not yet inducted validators
'queued_validators': [ValidatorRecord],
# List of removed validators pending withdrawal
'exited_validators': [ValidatorRecord]
```

Does this mean that a validator can join and leave the network only the during Crystallized state (which means only every 100th block)?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. For more details, read in the same spec e.g.:

> Dynasty transition - a change of the validator set
>
> #### Dynasty transition
>
> TODO. Stub for now.

And also:

> dynasty: The number of finalized checkpoints in the chain from root to the parent of a block. The dynasty is used to define when a validator starts and ends validating. The current dynasty only increments when a checkpoint is finalized as opposed to epoch numbers that increment regardless of finality.
>   — https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1011#Glossary

And [Casper FFG, section 3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.09437.pdf#section.3).

I'm not quoting that because StackExchange doesn't support LaTeX.

To summarise, dynasty transitions are dynamic, depending on the total number of validators, how many are requesting to leave and join at a given time and the rate of finalized checkpoints. The exact specification is TBD.